# Changing Formula sheet reference with Macro

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

Hello everyone i'm new to this site! i wanted to see if anyone could assist with a concept i believe is possible but don't know how to achieve it.

Essentially i have a formula that has Vlookups and references other sheets, this formula is the same but the sheet referenced changes for each column as each column references a different sheet. this is going to be done 135 times over 8 times.

```
=IF((IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,'[2015_Big_Book_Communication_10_19_15.xlsx]**Credit P-1**'!$C$2:$O$5000,9,FALSE),"Not Scheduled"))=0,1,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,'[2015_Big_Book_Communication_10_19_15.xlsx]**Credit P-1**'!$C$2:$O$5000,9,FALSE),"Not Scheduled"))
```

I want to use a macro to change the bolded sheet reference based upon a cell.

my idea is to have all the sheet names listed in a column and have the macro edit the equation for each row and then just paste the formulas transposed.

Is this possible?

Comment: A good place to start is with googling `how to use formulas in vba`.  but you could also put the sheet you want to reference in a new row at top then use the indirect function.  This will allow you to fill across and it will change.

Comment: You can use VBA and `Replace()` to edit the formulas: you could place the "before" and "after" sheet names in a lookup table and loop over that...

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I haven't found a good place to learn VBA overall so how i've been learning is finding codes, dissecting them and learning commands. the replace function is something i'll dive into Tim and i'll play with the indirect, Scott! Thanks again for the direction

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:

```
=IF((IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,INDIRECT("'[2015_Big_Book_Communication_10_19_15.xlsx]"&H3&"'!$C$2:$O$5000"),9,FALSE),"Not Scheduled"))=0,1,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,INDIRECT("'[2015_Big_Book_Communication_10_19_15.xlsx]"&H3&"'!$C$2:$O$5000"),9,FALSE),"Not Scheduled"))
```

In a column ("col H" in this example) write the sheet names and use indirect formula to refer to those names.

Comment: thanks for the help! this will save a lot of time, i've never used the indirect function. Exciting to add another tool to the box.